# Fulltext Search in MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance, search, entity, similarity

I am new to "searching" in MySQL and I have some tasks, which I don't know how to achieve them the best way.

I have the following MySQL-Table in my Database.

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `authors` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name_UNIQUE` (`name`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `name_fulltext` (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci$$
```

The task is: In a html form I want to enter a name, let's say "John Doe". This Name should be looked up in this table, in the column "name". I want the query to return all similar names like "John Due" or "John Doé" and so on. So the user can pick from a list the right name. Sometimes People want to look up a name like "John van Doe" (Netherland style). This should be displayed too in the list.

How is this best achieved? Or should I better ask. Is this possible? =) I am using a python cgi-script by the way, so any modules python can contribute are available.

Another question is: How do I look up Just "John" or "Dow"? Every name which has "John" in it shall be displayed. I tryed "WHERE name LIKE "John"" but this is way too slow. Is there a faster way?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Personally I think you should look into database normalization a little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The task is: In a html form I want to enter a name, let's say "John Doe". This Name should be looked up in this table, in the column "name". I want the query to return all similar names like "John Due" or "John Doé" and so on. So the user can pick from a list the right name. Sometimes People want to look up a name like "John van Doe" (Netherland style). This should be displayed too in the list.

`MySQL` does not support synonym dictionaries, so you should provide one yourself.

`Yahoo API` provides a spell correction service which you can use by submitting a query similar to this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    search.spelling
WHERE   query='juhn doe'
```

using this `URL`:

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT%20%20*%20%20FROM%20search.spelling%20WHERE%20query%20%3D%20'juhn%20doe'&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=cbfunc
```

As soon as you receive a list of synonyms, you may search for them using this query to `MySQL`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    authors
WHERE   MATCH(name) AGAINST ('(+juhn +doe) (+john +doe)' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

`John Doé` will be returned by this since you are using `UTF8_GENERAL_CI` which is case and accent insensitive.

If you want to look just for `John`, use this query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    authors
WHERE   MATCH(name) AGAINST ('+john' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Also, make sure you have parameter `ft_min_word_len` set to a reasonable value (`1` is best) in `my.cnf`.

Default is `4` which means that no three-letter surnames (like `Doe`) will be indexed.

Comment: Thank you very much! The last part of your response helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve the problem would be to create a [canonical form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonicalization) for names. The canonical name would be the same for all similar names. Then, when you want to find John Doe or John Doé or whatever, you'd first generate the canonical name, then do the lookup by that.

Of course, creating an algorithm to canonicalize human names is very difficult, if you want to get things like *Doe* and *Due* to correspond to each other. A simple base solution that would take care of the other cases you mention would be to strip all the accents (à -> a) and remove *von*, *van* etc.